# How to assign delegate for URLSessionDataTask?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am currently trying to make an `URLSessionDataTask` to a URI. Because the URI is redirected, I need to find out what is the redirected (final) URL. To do this, I want to use the `willPerformHTTPRedirection` method on `URLSessionDataDelegate` (this method is inherited from its super class `URLSessionDelegate`)

The problem is: I could not find a property on `URLSessionDataTask` to assign the delegate to.

From my understanding, if a class (say, `class A`) has a delegate class (say, `class ADelegate`), there should also have a property inside `class A` which is usually named with suffix `delegate`. When we want to implement method of a delegate, we instantiate an instance of the delegate class, and assign it to the delegate property. e.g. :

```
var instanceA = A()
var instanceADelegate = ADelegate()

instanceA.delegate = instanceADelegate
```

Is my understanding wrong? What is the correct way to implement method in `URLSessionDataDelegate` and then use it inside an `URLSessionDataTask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is: I could not find a property on URLSessionDataTask to assign the delegate to

Because the delegate belongs to the URLSession. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatatask):

> **protocol URLSessionDataDelegate**
>   The NSURLSessionDataDelegate protocol defines the methods that *a delegate of an 
>   URLSession*
>    object can implement to handle task-level events specific to data tasks and upload tasks.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: I think `willPerformHTTPRedirection` is actually in `URLSessionTaskDelegate`. How do I assign this to the `URLSession`? Do I set this on `URLSession.shared` and, if so, how?

Comment: @JoshParadroid Please consult the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession search for the term "delegate" within that page

Comment: For future reference: The delegate is set in the constructor of `URLSession`.